# PHP json_decode returns null on live server but works well on localhost

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON(approx 15MB) stored in the database. When I try to decode the JSON on localhost it works fine. But when I try to decode the same JSON on the live server it returns NULL.

I've tested the JSON on http://www.jsoneditoronline.org and it's perfectly valid.

Do I need to change some settings on Server?

Comment: yes, some code would nice

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this,to increase memory limit to 20 MB

```
ini_set('memory_limit','20M');
```